# Disposal must be plugged into above counter outlet to be used

Tags: electrical

My daughter just moved into a small apartment. The tiny kitchen requires you to plug in the disposal to a GFCI outlet that is on the wall above the stove in order to run it. There is no on/off switch. It just starts running when you plug it in. Plus, the cord drapes over the electric stove burners. This is the strangest set up I’ve seen and I told my daughter not to use the disposal and throw food waste in the trash. Is this a violation of the standards of electric code? Thanks.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: Codes can be different in different locales so adding general location will help.  It does sound like not the best idea, but think having it over the stove might be a no-no.

Comment: she can turn the disposal on and of using the push switch on the GFCI

Comment: Are there any outlets or junction boxes under the sink?  The unit was probably built without a disposal and a previous tenant installed one best he could.

Comment: how does the disposal cable comes on to of the counter, does it stay/lay there

Comment: Agree that she should just give up on the disposal. (And maybe find a new place to live...)

Comment: `GFCI` tends to indicate USA as a locale, but it's no guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

What a mess.

There are likely some relatively inexpensive fixes. But they involve getting an electrician in to do the work. An electrician because you can't work on it yourself (because it is a rental) and the landlord (or their handyman/maintenance person, unless a licensed electrician) can't do it either. Which = $$$, and in many places hard to get unless a true emergency.

The short-term fix that I would consider is, assuming the cord is long enough to be held up away from the burners (e.g., all the way at the back of the stove, at least several inches above the cooktop):

- Firmly attach the cable in a relatively safe location. Use big staples (designed for this) or cable ties. Of course, if the backsplash is tile then it gets tricky finding something secure/reliable that won't ruin the tile.
- Plug the disposal into a switch. Something like [this GE switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Grounded-Power-Switch-White-25511/206212328):

[image: GE switch]

Make sure it is UL or ETL listed, grounded, and rated for 15A. Some switches (bought via the internet rather than a local store) are *not* listed for safety and are hazardous. And some switches, even from major manufacturers, are rated for lower current, which is not a good idea for a switch on a disposal as the motor will draw heavy current on startup.

Comment: missed, when and how do you plug in to GFCI, that can not be moved, make a cable with plug into GFCI,

Answer (score 4):

I'd get a power strip with a switch on it. Plug it in over the stove and route it along the wall with tape, command strips, maybe an electrical staple or two to the countertop. Plug the disposal into the power strip and use the switch on it to turn it off and on.   Not knowing more, I'm not sure this makes sense, but it's the best I can come up with without knowing more.

Comment: We have a similar setup to reach a blender and rice cooker on the far end of the countertop. Do make sure the power strip is **away from any splash sources**! If this is not possible, I would go with the single switch that manassehkatz mentioned. It's still not exactly waterproof, but at least that one doesn't have open contacts when in use.